# how to show snack bar on top of modal bottom sheet in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, scaffold

When I use scaffoldmessenger to show snackbar it is shown behind the bottom sheet. When I wrap my bottom sheet with scaffold it is working fine .. but the bottom sheet is stretched for a full screen instead of showing at the bottom for a fixed height.. I know there are a lot of questions with same concept but nothing worked for me

```
 onPressed: () {
      showModalBottomSheet(
          isScrollControlled: true,
          context: context,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(25),
              topRight: Radius.circular(25),
            ),
          ),
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return Scaffold(
              body: Stack(children: [
                Positioned(
                  bottom: 0,
                  top: 0,
                  right: 0,
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: AnimatedPadding(
                      padding: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets,
                      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
                      curve: Curves.decelerate,
                      child: AddContactSection(myUID: myUID),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ]),
            );
          });
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, use `_isBottomSheetVisible` to determine whether to show the bottom sheet:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldMessengerState> _scaffoldKey =
      GlobalKey<ScaffoldMessengerState>();
  bool _isBottomSheetVisible = false;

  void _showSnackBar() {
    _scaffoldKey.currentState!.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
      content: Text('Hello, world!'),
    ));
  }

  void _toggleBottomSheet() {
    setState(() {
      _isBottomSheetVisible = !_isBottomSheetVisible;
    });
  }

  Widget _buildBottomSheet() {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: AnimatedPadding(
        padding: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets,
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
        curve: Curves.decelerate,
        child: Container(
          height: 200,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(25),
              topRight: Radius.circular(25),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScaffoldMessenger(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: _toggleBottomSheet,
                child: Text('Toggle Bottom Sheet'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: _showSnackBar,
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
        ),
        bottomSheet: _isBottomSheetVisible ? _buildBottomSheet() : null,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried that . I updated my code. it is still not working

Comment: @Sindu i updated my code, please try it

Answer (score 0):

Just add another `Scaffold()` to your `Bottom Sheet` and pass it to your new `scaffold key`